# Why can we consider elements of a normed space $X$ as elements of a normed space $Y$, if there is an embedding between these spaces?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\left|\;\cdot\;\right|)$ and $(Y,\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|)$ be normed spaces and $\iota :X\hookrightarrow Y$ be an embedding.

Often when I read that such an embedding $\iota$ exists, I read that we can consider the elements of $X$ as elements of $Y$. Why?

This is not trivial for me from the definition of an embedding. Moreover, what's meant by "we can consider the elements of $X$ as elements of $Y$"? That sounds like a much weaker property than being an element of $Y$ for each element of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $i$ is an embedding, we can consider $y=i(x)$ as $x$. This just means "if we relabel $y$ and call it $x$ instead, we actually do have $X\subset Y$". Of course, it still has the usual properties of $X$ as well $y_1=i(x_1),y_2=i(x_2)\implies y_1+y_2=i(x_1+x_2)$ and similarly for scalar multiplication.

The reason why this is valid is because $i(x)=i(x')$ means $x=x'$. The elements of $X$ are uniquely represented by a specific subset of $Y$ (namely, $i(X)$). For normed spaces there are additional requirements on the norm. For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}$ but *strictly* speaking, $\mathbb{Q}\nsubseteq\mathbb{R}$ (since $\mathbb{R}$ is formally defined as a set of Cauchy sequences of $\mathbb{Q}$ quotiented by some equivalence relation).

Comment: Does that mean that each embedding is a linear function?

Comment: We can uniquely represent the elements of $X$ by $\iota(X)$. So, when I talk about properties of $x\in X$ related to $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$, what I actually mean is the corresponding property of $\iota (x)$, right? However, I often see that people use $\left\|x\right\|$ directly. Is that common practice?

Comment: @0xbadf00d It probably is common practice because it is easier not to distinguish the two. Embeddings are injective morphisms and for normes spaces this means a linear map. In some contexts an embedding may or may not be an isometry as well.